# i have problem in installation of sklearn how i will solve this problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```bash
pip install sklearn
```

```bash
Collecting sklearn
  Using cached sklearn-0.0.post4.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\H_Ayyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4k88yzhj\sklearn_699b1b3e8634448894ffcf69795a5329\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
          LONG_DESCRIPTION = f.read()
        File "C:\python3.10.6\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 7: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.pip install sklearn
Collecting sklearn
  Using cached sklearn-0.0.post4.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\H_Ayyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4k88yzhj\sklearn_699b1b3e8634448894ffcf69795a5329\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
          LONG_DESCRIPTION = f.read()
        File "C:\python3.10.6\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 7: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have try many code and command on window but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You are installing `sklearn` using the old method (`pip install sklearn`) instead of `scikit-learn` (`pip install scikit-learn`).

The first one is deprecated (see [here](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/)) and the second one is what the GitHub repo said [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn).

The package name is `scikit-learn` but used using `import sklearn`.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest installing conda/Anaconda which is a great solution to avoid this kind of problems,it comes with the majority of data science tools installed.